# Problem with Python dict's __new__ method

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi i am making this class

```
class multiset(dict):

  def __new__(cls,iterabile):
      d = dict()
      for i in iterabile:
          if i not in d.keys():
              d[i] = iterabile.count(i)
      return super().__new__(cls,d)
```

This class is a custom dict that, from an input list, it create a dict where the keys are the element and the values are the number of occurences of the keys element in the list.
The problem is that the super().__new__(cls,d) return this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    m = multiset([1,1,1,2,1,3,2,3])

TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Comment: Not sure of the best solution, but the problem is that `dict.__init__` is getting called with the original list *after* `super().__new__` creates the object.

Comment: You could override `__init__` and ensure that `super().__init__` is called with the proper elements, but it would probably be better to not override `__new__` with new semantics. `dict.__new__` accepts an iterable argument, but it's supposed to be an iterable of key/value pairs.

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is not subclass `dict` at all; a multiset is not a kind of `dict`, though you can *implement* a multiset using a `dict`.

Comment: @chepner it doesnt work also with the key/value pairs, i tried super().__new__(cls,d.items())

Comment: `__new__` doesn't care about the dict and ignores it. If you override `__init__` and do nothing but call `super().__init__` with the same arguments, you'll see the error comes from `__init__`, not `__new__`.

Comment: Regarding inheritance: `m[1] = "foo"` is not a valid multiset operation and should not be allowed. Identify the operations that *do* make sense for a multiset, and implement them in terms of `dict` operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to using `__init__()` and don't create an explicit new dict because `self` is already a dict because multiset inherits from dict:

```
class multiset(dict):

  def __init__(self,iterable):
      for i in iterable:
          if i not in self.keys():
              self[i] = iterable.count(i)

m = multiset([1,1,1,2,1,3,2,3])
print( m )
# prints: {1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2}
```

But as ndclt points out, `collections.Counter` already does this.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> The dict() constructor builds dictionaries directly from sequences of key-value pairs:
>
> ```
> >>> dict([('sape', 4139), ('guido', 4127), ('jack', 4098)])
> {'sape': 4139, 'guido': 4127, 'jack': 4098}
> ```

And you're giving the dict constructor `super().__new__(cls,d)` which call the `dict.__init__` a dict instead of a key-value pairs.

Why don't use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which looks like to do what you want and behave like a dictionary:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([1,1,1,2,1,3,2,3])                                                                                                                         
Counter({1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2})
>>> Counter([1,1,1,2,1,3,2,3])[1]
4
```

Comment: `dict.__new__` doesn't actually care; it ignores the arguments. It's `dict.__init__` that gets called after `dict.__new__` returns that is complaining about the iterable argument.